# how to call SWRL rules from netbeans and retrieve data in netbeans .

Tags: netbeans, owl, protege, owl-api, swrl

I really need your help regarding calling SWRL rules from netbeans and retrieve data in netbeans .
I have servelet and jsp pages in my netbeans , i have owl-api as well.
I have ontology in my protege and 2 simple SWRL rules in side protege as well.

im new in this field and need to know how to call classes and from owlapi and how to send request to protege and how to return back the result of swrl ruls in netbeans by servelet .

it would be appreciated if you help me

sincerely

-- 
Mehdi Tarabi

Answer (score 0):

Results of SWRL rules require a reasoner supporting SWRL rules. The results of reasoning with SWRL rules are common axioms, there is no special method to obtain them. Protege is not required for this purpose; perhaps you're planning to use the SWRLAPI project?

Update: After reading the below comments, I'm convinced your best bet is using the SWRLAPI project. See [here](https://github.com/protegeproject/swrlapi) for its documentation and especially the section describing how to run SWRLAPI outside Protege:

> If you'd like to be able to execute SWRL rules or SQWRL queries you will need a SWRLAPI-based rule engine implementation. Currently, a Drools-based SWRL rule engine implementation is provided. This implementation is also hosted on Maven Central. Its dependency information can be found here: https://maven-badges.herokuapp.com/maven-central/edu.stanford.swrl/swrlapi-drools-engine

Comment: hi dear Ignazio- I have my ontology in protege v5 and inside protege I have one SWRL rules,   and when I run swrl rules its work fine inside protege . NOW  I wanna to send this results to my web application web.  I m working in netbeans and I have one JSP page as UI and one servlet  page as connection bridge . i wanna send result to servet and then from servlet to jsp to show on my UI.  . im student in norway and i need to finish this project . please help me on that.

Comment: or can I open my OWL fine in netbeans and then run SWRL rules inside netbeans?/

Comment: hi . my project ins not maven. it is java web application do you think i can use SWRL API?

Comment: You could use maven to build your web application. Otherwise you'll have to manage all dependencies manually.